# Does not work in url friendly php method GET

Tags: php

I create url As follows:

example[dot]com/index.php?c=2

to

example[dot]com/any/2

I want use url Like http://example.com/any/2?p=1 for get Variable 'p' in php

And do not want use url frindly for get Variable 'p'

Is it possible?

this my code in .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ ./index.php?c=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the `QSA` flag, so that an already existing query string does not get discarded, but is kept and merged with the new one you specified in your rewrite target.

For more details, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa